# BarButton Item defaulting to center of navigation bar

Tags: swift

Im adding a BarButtonItem to a Navigation Bar. This Navigation Controller and Bar don't come from the storyboard and are instead generated programmatically. An issue I've noticed because of this is that the location any BarButton Items are in the center of the navigation bar. Whether it be a RightBarButton or LeftBarButton, the button always appears in the center of the bar. My suspicion is that the available space for button items is zero, causing the buttons to default to the center location. I've attached my code below. Where does the issue arise from?

Creating navigation controller programmatically:

```
let popoverContent = Itinerary()
popoverContent.parentController = self
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
popover?.sourceView = self.view
nav.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 154/255, green: 203/255, blue: 231/255, alpha: 1)
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Adding the BarButtonItems from inside the Itinerary View:

```
let button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        let img = UIImage.init(named: "xbutton")
        button.setImage(img, for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissItin), for: .touchUpInside)
        let Barbutton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = Barbutton
```

Comment: Your code works fine!!

Comment: @AgentSmith If it is correct, do you know why the button does appear on the right side of the navigation bar?

Comment: I used your code and the button is appearing in its place on right!